# Why i can't modify these values in an object?

Tags: c#

I have a problem, if i want to edit a value into an object and call it again, i get the old value instead of the new one.

Here is my Function to get the Class:

```
 public static Clan GetClanByID(int Index)
    {
        foreach (Clan Clan in Clans)
        {
            if (Clan.ID == Index)
            {
                return Clan;
            }
        }

        return new Clan()
        {
            ID = -1,
            Name = "NULL",
            IconID = -1
        };
    }
```

Here is my function to update the Value:

```
public static void ChangeAnnouncement(int ClanID, int Mode, string Text)
    {
        if (ClanID != -1)
        {
            Clan Clan = GetClanByID(ClanID);

            if (Mode == 0)
            {
                Clan.Description = Text;
            }
            else if (Mode == 1)
            {
                Clan.News = Text;
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is the class:

```
public class Clan
{
    public int ID;
    public int LeaderID;
    public int Extension;
    public int CreationDate;
    public long EXP;
    public long IconID;
    public string Name;
    public string News;
    public string Description;
    public List<ClanWars> ClanWars;
    public List<ClanUsers> Users;
    public List<ClanCoMasters> CoMasters;
    public List<ClanPendingUsers> PendingUsers;
    public LeaderInformations LeaderInformations;
}
```

Example: The old value was "123", than i call the function ChangeAnnouncement, and set the value to "1234567890", after that i get the value using GetClanByID(ID).Description, but i will still get the old value ("123")

I Hope you can help me.

Comment: This is why you shouldn't make mutable structs.

Comment: You haven't declared any structs... why are you talking about them? Note that if you don't find a clan, you're creating a new one - but not adding it to your collection.

Comment: I edited your question. You said 'structure' but used a class, so I dropped all the mentions to 'structure'. `Structure` as a special meaning in C#. For one, they are supposed to be immutable. You didn't actually create a structure, but a class.

Answer (score 1):

You're returning a new Clan every time. You forgot adding the newly created clan to `Clans`.

Comment: Im adding the newly created clan to Clans.

Comment: @lokko Then it happens somewhere outside of code you've provided.

Comment: Oh, is that mode of the clan you're changing 1, perhaps?

Comment: ChangeAnnouncement gets a mode - if it's 1, it changes News and not Description.